# How to align 5 images in a row in bootstrap grid system?

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I have a screenshot as show below which I have replicated by using bootstrap 4.1

[image]

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7nzvby9o/embedded/result) for that **but it is still not properly aligned as images are very close to each other**.

The HTML code which I have used in the fiddle in order to replicate the above screenshot is:

```
<div class="container text-center border">
<div class="hello_world">
   <img src="https://image.ibb.co/fxj2nJ/image1.png" alt="image1">
   <img src="https://image.ibb.co/gZyHMd/image2.png" alt="image2">
   <img src="https://image.ibb.co/mGTpZy/image3.png" alt="image3">
   <img src="https://image.ibb.co/bZkKZy/image4.png" alt="image4">
   <img src="https://image.ibb.co/dF42nJ/image5.png" alt="image5">
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering how I can use bootstrap grid system in order to replicate the above screenshot. As there are 5 images, so I am not sure how I can divide list of 5 images into sum of 12.

Comment: Why you don't set full width to container and use `@media` to manually set images size?

Comment: @ventaquil The reason why I am not using container as full width because I want margin left and margin right, spacing on left and right.

Comment: and how do you see this images on mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple proof-of-concept: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/7nzvby9o/13/).

In CSS I used `flex` display mode and `justify-content` property

```
#images {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

You can add padding or margin to this model.

If you want different view in mobile or tablet just use `@media`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I am wondering what is the purpose of using `<div class="col text-center">` ?

Comment: Also height of images is constant in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7nzvby9o/18/embedded/result) which is 98 px. I don't want this to happen. I want the fiddle to take the regular size of an image. Is there any way we can do that ?

Comment: @user5447339 here you go [https://jsfiddle.net/7nzvby9o/20/](https://jsfiddle.net/7nzvby9o/20/). I used `col` class to fill container with full column.